# Rename all columns in a table removing whitespace

Tags: mysql

I have a table which I imported from a very large CSV which has over 100 columns. I've just noticed they've imported with spaces in the column names.

Is there a way to rename all columns and remove the spaces?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following query will remove all whitespace from column names containing any white space in the table `your_table` in the database `your_database`.  You can replace with the values you need.

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(
           'ALTER TABLE ', C.TABLE_NAME, ' CHANGE `', 
           C.COLUMN_NAME, '` `', REPLACE(C.COLUMN_NAME, ' ', ''), '` ',
           C.DATA_TYPE, ';'
          )
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C
WHERE
    TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your_database' AND TABLE_NAME = 'your_table'
    AND C.COLUMN_NAME LIKE '% %';
```

Pay very close attention to the backticks which surround the column name (including the new column name).  This will output a set of `ALTER TABLE` statements which look like the following:

```
ALTER TABLE your_table CHANGE `Old Column Name` `OldColumnName` VARCHAR;
```

Comment: Amazing! The only thing I needed to change was to put the varchar size as: varchar (1024).

Answer (score -1):

Try this system procedure:

```
EXEC sp_RENAME 'TableName.OldName' , 'NewName', 'COLUMN'
```

Comment: Sorry to be clear lets say I have a column called 'Order ID' I want it to be 'OrderID'

Comment: EXEC sp_RENAME 'TableName.Order ID' , 'OrderID', 'COLUMN'